# How to remove values with a callback on async.map using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cheerio

I'm using Node.js and cheerio to crawl some urls and I want to see whether the urls contain certain elements.  If they satisfy the condition I want to keep them in the array but if they don't I want to remove them.

```
function runRequest(url, cb) {
  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {
      //load the cheerio object
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      if (/*some condition isn't satisfied*/) {
        //i can only return null
        cb(null, null);
      } else {
        //keep url in the array
        cb(null, url); 
      }
    }
  });
}
async.map(urls, runRequest, function (err, results) {
  //results should now only contain some of the urls if the urls didn't satisfy the condition
  console.log(results);
});
```

while firing the callback with null as a parameter is a solid workaround, I was wondering if there's a way I can fire the callback but essentially remove the element from the array, because making it null causes other problems for me.  (If I don't fire the callback on the 2nd param in async.map the 3rd param doesn't even run).

Comment: What other problems does it cause? Would you filtering out the bulbuls in the final callback solve your problems?

Comment: Why don't you just use `async.filter` instead of `async.map`?